# Converting into polar form for integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

So I am presented with a double integral which is can be evaluated easily enough as is.

$$\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int _{\sqrt{3}y}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}xy^2 dxdy.$$

What I'm curious about is converting this into polar form then integrating it, and this is where I'm having trouble with.

I try to establish the bounds for $r$ but I end up cancelling $r$ out for the bounds, and when I convert $xy^2$ into polar I get a weird mess I can't really simplify. What I try to integrate doesn't come out to be an "area".

Is there something simple I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you draw a picture of the region? That is pretty much essential. The region of integration is a sector of the unit circle, with $0\le\theta\le \pi/6$. (Note that $x=\sqrt3y$ is the line $y=\frac1{\sqrt3}x$, which indeed makes an angle of $\pi/6$ with the $x$-axis. The equation $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ gives a portion of the unit circle.) Thus, you end up with the integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_0^1 r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: So I did, but where I was stuck was trying to write it out without referring to the graphs or any visual reference and just show it by writing out the regions in rectangular form, converting it to polar, and finding the bounds that way, mostly for practice and mostly for sheer curiosity. Maybe I overthought the problem now that I've seen this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BobPoberton It's all but impossible to do this without drawing a picture/understanding *something* about the shape of the boundary. Otherwise you don't know how many $r$-simple and $\theta$-simple (or "type I and type II in $r\theta$-space") regions you'd need to decompose it into. But you don't need to know in advance that there's no horizontal line segment part of the boundary at $y=1/2$.